# How to access input of state machine in any node at AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Let's say I have this state machine in AWS Step Function:

[image: step function example]

And I had started it with this input:

```
{
  "item1": 1,
  "item2": 2,
  "item3": 3
}
```

It's clear for me that `Action A` is receiving the input payload. But, how can `Action C` access the state machine input to get the value of `item3`? Is it possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, the data available in `Action C` will be dependent on what the result/output of `Action B` is.

However, if you just care about the original input to the state machine execution, you can set the payload of `Action C` using the **Context Object**.

```js
// roughly 
 "Action C": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
   "Parameters": {
     "Payload.$": "$$.Execution.Input",
     "FunctionName": "<action c lambda>"
 },
```

Check out the [AWS documentation for Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html)

Comment: Thanks deric4, I could access the item like you said: "$$.Execution.Input.item3"