# How can I pass input data through AWS step functions with nested step functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function with three steps:

1. setup
2. start & wait for finish of another step function
3. finish

I pass some input from the first step into the second step, but I don't use all fields as inputs to the child step function, but I want to pass all of that data into step 3. I thought I could do this by specifying `OutputPath`, but it doesn't work and still passes through the output of the child step function to step 3.

```
  stateMachine: {
    StartAt: 'setup',
    States: {
      setup: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Retry: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            MaxAttempts: 2,
          },
        ],
        Resource: setupFn,
        Next: 'child_sfn',
      },
      child_sfn: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Retry: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            MaxAttempts: 2,
          },
        ],
        Catch: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            Next: 'sfn_catch',
          },
        ],
        Parameters: {
          StateMachineArn: 'mySfnArn',
          Input: {
            'myInput1.$': '$.myInput1',
          },
        },
        OutputPath: '$.',
        Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync',
        Next: 'finish',
      },
      finish: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Retry: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            MaxAttempts: 2,
          },
        ],
        Resource: finishFn,
        End: true,
      },
      sfn_catch: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Resource: stepFunctionCatch,
        End: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case *you only need the inputs* that were provided to `step 1 [setup]` to be passed to `step 3 [finish]`

you should be able to access the *Execution Input* via the Context Object as described in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71230038/4526019

---

If `step 3 [finish]` needs the input to `step 1 [setup]` *AND* the output from `step 2 [child_sfn]` you can use `ResultPath` to avoid clobbering the payload.

I'll try and show what I mean with a SFN with a single state:

⚠️ *Note: `Pass` types are obviously different than `Task` types but the premise is the same*

Parent SFN Input:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "value": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "value": 2
  },
  "c": {
    "value": 3
  }
}
```

SFN Defintion where only the `a` and `b` keys from the input should be passed, but *NOT* `c`. The "built-up" state can be preserved by creating a new key that can be safely/predictably appended to by using `ResultPath` and can be consumed by some downstream task.

```json
{
  "StartAt": "Step1",
  "States": {
    "Step1": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "params.$": "$['a', 'b']"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.stateOutput.Step1",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Output (with preserved input and "tranformed" output created by `Step1`)

```json
{
  "a": {
    "v": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "v": 2
  },
  "c": {
    "v": 3
  },
  "stateOutput": {
    "Step1": {
      "params": {
        "a": {
          "v": 1
        },
        "b": {
          "v": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, using `OutputPath` in `StepX` is gonna wipe out all the input that may have been built up by all the previous steps. [example from docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html)

---

The workflow that I've found most useful, although extremely tedious, is to manually write out the json before and each "phase"(?) when defining the state and making any notes along the way:

- **phase_0**: output put from previous state

  ```json
  {
     "a": {
       "value": 1
     },
     "b": {
       "value": 2
     },
     "c": {
       "value": 3
     }
  }
  ```

  - **phase_1**: using `InputPath`?

    If InputPath is defined, only send part of **phase_0**. This basically throws everything else away.

    ```json
    {
      "//": "json object after InputPath"
    }
    ```

    - **phase_2**:  redefine the `Payload` sent to the task via `Parameters`

      The object definition for what is actually sent to your lambda

      ```json
      {
          "//": "json object sent to the task after defining Payload.Parameters"
      }
      ```
    - **phase_3**: raw output from task

      i.e. the response from lambda

      ```json
      {
          "//": "json object returned from lambda"
      }
      ```
  - **phase_4**: optionally customize output from phase_3 with `ResultSelector`

    ```json
    {
      "//": "transform the result returned by lambda (similar to Parameters.Payload)"
    }
    ```
- **phase_5**: optionally set `ResultPath`?

  inserts the the object of **phase_3** into the object of **phase_1** at the specified path

  ```json
  {
     "//": "roughly object in phase_1 updated with object in phase_4"
  }
  ```
- **phase_6**: optionally set `OutputPath`

  throw away everything except `OutputPath` and feed it to the next state

  ```json
  {
    "//": "this is what will be the input to the next state"
  }
  ```

Hopefully that helps and doesn't cause more confusion. I know I've spent too many hours trying to decipher the docs and map that to my own use cases

Comment: Thank you for the examples! So I'm trying to use ResultPath to insert the output of my inner step function run into my step1 input, but in step3, I still get the step function's raw output as the input to step3. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: edit: sorry just saw you answered already :)
@BenWu what are you setting the result path to?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why, but using `ResultPath` in both my step1 and step2 worked. So something like

```
stateMachine: {
    StartAt: 'setup',
    States: {
      setup: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Retry: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            MaxAttempts: 2,
          },
        ],
        ResultPath: '$.data',
        Resource: setupFn,
        Next: 'child_sfn',
      },
      child_sfn: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Retry: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            MaxAttempts: 2,
          },
        ],
        Catch: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            Next: 'sfn_catch',
          },
        ],
        Parameters: {
          StateMachineArn: 'mySfnArn',
          Input: {
            'myInput1.$': '$.myInput1',
          },
        },
        ResultPath: '$.sfnOutput',
        Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync',
        Next: 'finish',
      },
      finish: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Retry: [
          {
            ErrorEquals: ['States.ALL'],
            MaxAttempts: 2,
          },
        ],
        Resource: finishFn,
        End: true,
      },
      sfn_catch: {
        Type: 'Task',
        TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
        Resource: stepFunctionCatch,
        End: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).